# ASP.NET Web API: convert Object Literal to CLR class

Tags: asp.net-web-api

My Web API controller needs to take in a property bag, i.e. a list of key-value pairs, which it will use to insert or update records of indeterminate type. My ideal code would look something like this. This example would be to insert a new record.

Route:

```
/api/data/{EntityName}
```

Data from client, passed in using jQuery.ajax() (or similar) with POST:

```
URI: 
http://mysite/api/data/employee

Post data:
"values":
{"FirstName":"Jim",
 "LasName":"Nobody",
 "StartDate": new Date(),
 "Salary": 100000 }
```

Web API Controller function:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutRecord(string entity, ??? values)
{
    // confirm valid entity, look up metadata.
    // Take values from "values" and feed them into my framework to insert a new employee.
}
```

What is the ideal configuration to accomplish this? What would be the type for "values" in the controller method - possibly a Dictionary< string,object>?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a model that has all of the properties, the model binder will map your post data directly to the model.

So your post would look more like this:

```
$.post(url, {FirstName:'Jim', LasName: 'NoBody',StartDate: someDate, Salary: 10000},
 function(data){
         // do something with callback
    });
```

And your action would look like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutRecord(string entity, employeeModel model)
{
    // confirm valid entity, look up metadata.
    // Take values from "values" and feed them into my framework to insert a new employee.
}
```

This is a tad more type safe than the property bag approach, and save you a lot of casting and typing issues.

Comment: Thanks Maess, but what I'm really after is the ability to work with objects of *indeterminate* type (so yes, less type safe.) My goal is to set up a single controller to handle CRUD operations for *all* of the classes in my framework. The framework I'm working with already has this ability so I just need to get the Web API part set up. Accomplishing my desired configuration would get me 1 controller instead of 100+ which would be a real win for me.

Comment: I think the restful approach you are taking may not be the best for your application as you will not have an enforceable contract with the service. I missed the entity name portion of your post.  In your approach if you go with Json, you could have a values class that is a set of name value pairs.  Your controller would just take in an instance of that object as the model binder will handle it for you.

Comment: @BarryFandango That sounds absolutely horrific as a concept, although it may seem very convenient it is not very restful.

Comment: Think of it this way: I have a system which can insert, update and delete records of indeterminate type. Some entities are completely custom, so they have no strong type representation at all. This is not a matter of convenience - if I create 100+ strongly typed controllers I still couldn't support custom entities. Are you saying such a system could never have a RESTful interface?

Comment: Also I don't think the definition of RESTful includes strongly typed model binding. That's part of ASP.NET MVC and Web API (among others,) but you won't find mention of it in any HTTP RFC. After all what is an HTML form post but a collection of name/value pairs? But that's a longer conversation :)